# How to count sessions in asp.net server application

Tags: asp.net

There is a way to manage how many sessions an asp.net running aplication have? I want to exhibit it in a page, maybe with some other important information, if available. And, how can I do it?

Comment: Yes, it is! But if we can obtain more valuable information, like resources consuption, it should be great!

Comment: Ok. In my answer, you could retrieve, update, and store an array (instead of individual App elements) of user information from Session as well. You would have one nice array of all your user info.

Comment: is your App using ***stateserver*** or ***InProc*** ? Maybe using _Performance Monitor stats_ (programmatically via *WMI*)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In `global.asax`, do the following:

Handle the `Application.Start` event adding the following:

```
Application["LiveSessionsCount"] = 0;
```

Handle the `Session.Start` event adding the following:

```
Application["LiveSessionsCount"] = ((int) Application["LiveSessionsCount"]) + 1;
```

Handle the `Session.End` event adding the following:

```
Application["LiveSessionsCount"] = ((int) Application["LiveSessionsCount"]) - 1;
```

To retrieve sessions count inside your page write the following:

```
int LiveSessionsCount = (int) Application["LiveSessionsCount"];
```

Comment: @Haris Read: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21156/ASP-NET-HttpModule-for-handling-session-end-with-S

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41192294/903783 - lock/unlock is needed since read, increment and set a value are three steps and in between them sessions may have been created or terminated in parallel

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps in your global.asax file Session_Start and Session_End events, you can store session information to a userinfo array within your application state object. Then you can manage this array from App State throughout your application.

Comment: This solution counts all values stored in the application object, not just the number of sessions. It also wastes a large amount of memory for busy sites. All you need is a single integer.

Comment: @ShadowChaser He wants to 'manage' Session information, not just have a count of how many people are logged in. Although, I should have a single array within App State that stores this information.

Comment: Note: *stateserver* `Session_End` will not work , only for ***InProc***