# ASP.NET WebApi 2 get all active sessions (users) in the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp.net-web-api

I have a server on the WebApi2, and I need get all active users on the server.
How to implement it?
I think, maybe, save customerId after **logIn** in the session storage.
But I don't know how to implement it.

Or maybe exists some best solutions for it.
Help me please, with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access session object using [this kind of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594229/accessing-session-using-asp-net-web-api).

Keep in mind that Web API provides [REST services](http://ruben.verborgh.org/blog/2012/08/24/rest-wheres-my-state/), and is from a design perpective not meant to access Session objects, as its purpose is to provide [stateless methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105296/if-rest-applications-are-supposed-to-be-stateless-how-do-you-manage-sessions).

This of course does not mean it is not technically feasible, as you can see on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6218525/2952074).

Answer (score 1):

Use this article [Adding Session support to ASP.NET Web API](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/11/adding-session-support-to-asp-net-web-api/) for example

as the entering point to find out the best solution.

Comment: I don't see in this code some method for added some data, just update. But I need to get all active sessions (not just one )?

Comment: @bsoulier thanks a lot, I think it is best solutions for me.